# AppleScript application asking for permission to access Desktop after full disk access (macOS Ventura)

Tags: applescript, permission, python, ventura

I created an AppleScript which executes a simple Python file.

I've given it full disk access but still every time it runs it prompts a "X would like to access files in your Desktop folder" message.

Is there a way to make this popup stop?
[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Seems pretty clear to me - they've got a script with full disk access but it's still requesting access, they want to know how to make it stop

Comment: Is this is for a script _application_?

Comment: Basically what the AppleScript does is run a `do shell script` which executes a python script. I exported it as an _application_ file format and _Run-only_ as the option.

Comment: AppleScript has historically saved all properties and globals _by writing to the script file_, so the security system puts up the dialog again because it is seen as a different app - one that hasn’t been given permission yet.  The solution is to code-sign the app (you can use a self-issued certificate), or otherwise make the script(s) in the bundle read-only.

Comment: Code signing with my Apple Development account seems to fix the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AppleScript has historically saved all properties and globals *by writing to the script file*, so the security system puts up the dialog again because it is seen as a different app - one that hasn’t been given permission yet.

The solution is to code-sign the app (you can use a self-issued certificate), or otherwise make the script(s) in the bundle read-only.